# Do dependency filters and interceptors get applied

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've got a Java spring boot app A that's got a maven dependency B. Let's assume B has got filters, resolvers or interceptors that I have not specifically called anywhere in my app A. Would there be a scenario in which they would still be applied to the incoming requests in app A?

My main class in app A has only got the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation and no further `@Configuration`, `@Bean` or `@ComponentScanning` happening anywhere in the app.

Cheers,
Kris

Answer (score 0):

I hope without registering filter it will not enabled .

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestResponseLoggingFilter>
```